# How to Speed-Up Writing Dataframe to s3 from EMR PySpark Notebook?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-emr

So I'm learning PySpark by playing around with the DMOZ dataset in a jupyter notebook attached to an EMR cluster. The process I'm trying to achieve is as follows:

1. Load a csv with the location of files in an s3 public dataset in to a PySpark DataFrame (~130k rows)
2. Map over the DF with a function that retrieves the file contents (html) and rips the text
3. Join the output with the original DF as a new column
4. Write the joined DF to s3 (the problem: It seems to hang forever, its not a large job and the output json should only be a few gigs)

All of the writing is done in a function called run_job()

I let it sit for about 2 hours on a cluster with 10 m5.8xlarge instances which *should* be enough (?). All of the other steps execute fine on their own, except for the df.write(). I have tested on a
much smaller subset and it wrote to s3 with no issue, but when I go to do the whole file it seemingly hangs at at "0/n jobs complete."

I am new to PySpark and distributed computing in general, so its probably a simple "best practice" that I am missing. **(Edit: Maybe its in the config of the notebook? I'm not using any magics to configure spark currently, do I need to?)**

Code below...

```
import html2text

import boto3
import botocore

import os
import re
import zlib
import gzip

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from bs4 import Comment

# from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
# from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, SparkSession
# from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, LongType

import logging

def load_index():
        input_file='s3://cc-stuff/uploads/DMOZ_bussineses_ccindex.csv'
        df = spark.read.option("header",True) \
             .csv(input_file)
        #df = df.select('url_surtkey','warc_filename', 'warc_record_offset', 'warc_record_length','content_charset','content_languages','fetch_time','fetch_status','content_mime_type')
        return df
    
def process_warcs(id_,iterator):
        html_textract = html2text.HTML2Text()
        html_textract.ignore_links = True
        html_textract.ignore_images = True

        no_sign_request = botocore.client.Config(signature_version=botocore.UNSIGNED)
        s3client = boto3.client('s3', config=no_sign_request)

        text = None
        s3pattern = re.compile('^s3://([^/]+)/(.+)')
        PREFIX = "s3://commoncrawl/"

        for row in iterator:
            try:

                start_byte = int(row['warc_record_offset'])
                stop_byte = (start_byte + int(row['warc_record_length']))

                s3match = s3pattern.match((PREFIX + row['warc_filename']))
                bucketname = s3match.group(1)
                path = s3match.group(2)

                #print('Bucketname: ',bucketname,'\nPath: ',path)
                resp = s3client.get_object(Bucket=bucketname, Key=path, Range='bytes={}-{}'.format(start_byte, stop_byte))

                content = resp['Body'].read()#.decode()

                data = zlib.decompress(content, wbits = zlib.MAX_WBITS | 16).decode('utf-8',errors='ignore')
                data = data.split('\r\n\r\n',2)[2]

                soup = bs(data,'html.parser')

                for x in soup.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment)):
                    x.extract()  
                for x in soup.find_all(["head","script","button","form","noscript","style"]):
                    x.decompose()

                text = html_textract.handle(str(soup))

            except Exception as e:
                pass

            yield (id_,text)
            
def run_job(write_out=True):
        df = load_index()
        df2 = df.rdd.repartition(200).mapPartitionsWithIndex(process_warcs).toDF()
        df2 = df2.withColumnRenamed('_1','idx').withColumnRenamed('_2','page_md')
        df = df.join(df2.select('page_md'))
        if write_out:             
            output = "s3://cc-stuff/emr-out/DMOZ_bussineses_ccHTML"
            df.coalesce(4).write.json(output) 
        return df

df = run_job(write_out=True)
```

Comment: You havent shared what is the current bottlenext, what do you want to speed up? whats are the current benchmarks

Comment: The bottleneck is that pyspark seems to just hang when I go to save the final DF to s3. I don't currently have a benchmark, I let it run on various configurations with the largest being 10 m5.8xlarge core nodes, and after 2 hours I terminated as I figured I was doing something wrong. Its a relatively small job and the total file is probably only a few gigs max.

Comment: Have you cheched output logs and errors (stdout and stderr)?

Comment: I will check the default logs now. I am going to add some logging to the exception and will update with results.

Comment: I checked the logs and I still have no idea. Spent another $50 on EMR though trying to make it work though :-) . Maybe its the config?

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to make it work. I attribute this to either of the 2 changes below. I also changed the hardware configuration and opted for a higher quantity of smaller instances. Gosh I just LOVE it when I spend an entire day in a deep state of utter confusion when all I needed to do was add an "/" to the save location......

1. **I added a trailing "/" to the output file location in s3**

1 Old:

```
 output = "s3://cc-stuff/emr-out/DMOZ_bussineses_ccHTML"
```

1 New:

```
 output = "s3://cc-stuff/emr-out/DMOZ_bussineses_ccHTML/"
```

2. **I removed the "coalesce" in the "run_job()" function**, I have 200 output files now, but it worked and it was super quick (under 1 min).

2 Old:

```
 df.coalesce(4).write.json(output)
```

2 New:

```
 df.write.mode('overwrite').json(output)
```